# Dynamically add ProhibitNullCharactersValidator into the form's __init__ in Django. Need an advice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

Quite a simple question for someone who knows the answer.

Is it possible to dynamically add validator to a form’s field in froms **init** ???

I want to do something like this:

```py
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = kwargs.pop("pk", None)
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        if self.pk == some integer:
    self.fields[field].validator(s)……..  # and I don’t know what to type here
        else:
    do something else…
```

Goal is to add ProhibitNullCharactersValidator dynamically depending on the self.pk to self.fields[field]  (one field of the form)

Thank you in advance and sorry if this questions is dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add the validator to a particular field you can override the `clean_` method for that field, and call the validator there.

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_myfield(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('myfield')
        if self.instance.pk == some_value:
            ProhibitNullCharactersValidator(value)
        return value
```